# Responses in Event Driven Architecture

Tags: rest, events, microservices

The classic EDA example involves a **command** triggering events - like a chain of dominos.

`PlaceOrder` -> `OrderPlaced` -> `PaymentSucceeded` -> `OrderShipped`

Typically the *Order Service* listens to events along the way to keep the status of the order updated.  *Presumably* (and this is the part that every article skips!) because at some point the order service will receive a `ViewOrder` command, which will require a response beyond "OK".

So my question is:  In a EDA, do at least some of your services have to react to both events *and* commands?

If not, what architecture could separate the "command world" (required for supporting a HTTP API) from the "event world" of services performing async processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, every microservice we've built does both things.  Participating with the Messaging Plane (publishing and/or subscribing) is always a requirement, and in *most* cases, exposing at least one API endpoint is also a requirement.  In fact I don't believe we have any live services that don't expose an API endpoint although we have a few that probably could be that way.

So far, we've not run into a case where there was value in splitting a service into separate parts for API serving vs event bus interaction.  I wouldn't say that's impossible, but we are very focused on services encapsulating a (functional) domain without much concern for implementation.  That has allowed us to use a very formulaic approach to creating services themselves which is a big part of why we chose this architecture style.